# Carrying over a user's information to a new page and then editing it

Tags: php, html, forms

I am outputting all of my user's into a table on a page I have called admincustomers.php. I am then attempting to select EDIT on a specific users record. I then route that to a page called editusers.php. I then want all of that specific users information to be outputted on that page. I am not displaying all of the user information I have in my table on admincustomers.php. So when the edit page loads I want to get all of that users information so I have the ability to edit it.

The issue I am having is I am not quite sure how I can carry over the customers ID and get the information to the next page.

admincustomers.php page

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
?>                  
                            <table class="tableproduct">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="thproduct">ID</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct">First Name</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct">Last Name</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct">Email</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct">Username</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct">Group</th>
                                    <th class="thproduct"></th>
                                    <th class="thproduct"></th>
                                </tr>   
<?php   
     if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
       mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ". $_POST['id'] ."")
       or die("Could not DELETE: " . mysqli_error($con));
         "Your product was successfully deleted."; 
}   else {Session::flash('adminusers', 'User was successfully deleted.');
}   
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) : 
?>
                            <form method="POST" action="admincustomers.php">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> </td> 
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?> </td>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['group']; ?> </td>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><a href='edituser.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
                                    <td class="tdproduct"><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE "/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </form> 

<?php   
endwhile;
//Delete message
    if(Session::exists('adminusers')) {
        echo '<p>' . Session::flash('adminusers') . '</p>';
    }
?>
                        </table>
```

editusers.php page

I'm trying to escape the users data, but I only get my user information escaped onto the page.

```
<?php
    $_GET['id'];
?>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="inputbar" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->firstname); ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->lastname); ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->email); ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>" required>
                            </div>  

                                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                                <label for="signinButton">
                                    <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
                                </label>
                        </form>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I go about fixing this issue?

UPDATE:

$user variable

```
public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user) {
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)) {
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                // process Logout
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->find($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `$user` on `editusers.php`?

Comment: The variable $user is set in my user class. I am on a PHP framework.

Comment: Is it set to the data for the user whose ID is in `$_GET['id']`? If you're getting the wrong user, it sounds like you're not doing that.

Comment: The most relevant code seems to be the part that creates the `user` object, which you haven't shown.

Comment: I can remove the $user variable. I am just not sure how to get the current user's ID that I have selected. I can make a new variable, just not sure how to structure it

Comment: Don't get rid of `$user`, just make sure you're setting it to the correct user.

Comment: Then you'll get the selected user, instead of always showing your own user information.

Comment: I have updated my question and put my user variable in it. It is set to the current user in the session, so I'm not sure how I can change that. I really do not want to change my class, so I will need to change it on my page...just not sure how to do it for the current ID selected.

Comment: I would ideally like it to work without the user class at all. Just code grabbing the id and outputting the results from that id. I have other parts of my site I have to configure this with that do not correlate with the user variable, so it would help out a ton.

Comment: You need to create another `User` object for the user you want to edit. But it looks like your `User` class assumes that the only user it manages is the logged in user, not other users in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `editusers.php` script, look up the user in `$_GET['id']` and use that information, not `$user`.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, username FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $email, $username);
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="inputbar" value="<?php echo htmlentities($firstname); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lastname); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" required>
        </div>  

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <label for="signinButton">
                <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
            </label>
    </form>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div>
    User <?php echo htmlentities($_GET['id']); ?> not found.
<? 
}
```

Comment: It is giving me a syntax error for the } in this line.... <?php } else { ?>..... I tried removing the }, but then it gave an invalid elsestatement error.

Comment: Did you have `<?php` at the beginning? I left that out of my answer.

Comment: It looks like the code is breaking right after the 'firstname' label. Because the only thing that shows up is the words Firstname

Comment: I had a typo in the first `htmlentities`

Comment: PERFECT. Thanks I appreciate it! I'll be able to use this all over the board now.